# Pandas - directly add moving average columns from group by to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, moving-average, split-apply-combine

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
name, date, day_index, value
```

I want to add a 4th column to the same dataframe which is the exponentially weighted moving average of the 3rd column (value) for each name, sorted by first date and then day_index. I can generate this as a series using the following code.

```
df.sort_values(['date','day_index'],inplace=True)

ecw_series = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: 
x["value"].ewm(halflife=2).mean())
```

However, if I try and directly add this to the original dataframe, I get the following error:

```
df['ecw'] =  df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: 
x["value"].ewm(halflife=2).mean())



incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

And if I try and merge the series with the dataframe I get the following error:

```
df['index'] = df.index

df = df.merge(ecw_series, left_on=['name','index'],right_index=True)

can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 
'pandas.core.series.Series'
```

At this point, I was considering converting the series to a dataframe, and then merging. But I am sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach works:

```
df['ecw'] = model_df.groupby('name')['value'].apply(lambda x: 
 x.ewm(halflife=2).mean())
```

I am still slightly confused by why you cannot reference the 'value' column within the Lambda function.

Comment: If you reference by column, you have to specify axis=1:

`ecw_series = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x["value"].ewm(halflife=2).mean(), axis=1)`